# PHP GD imagefill -- fill to left of source

Tags: php, gd

I am extending an image canvas with PHP gd:

```
    $newimage = imagecreatetruecolor($imageWidth + 840, $imageHeight);
    $color = imagecolorallocate($newimage, 0, 0, 0);
    imagefill($newimage, 0, 0, $color);
    imagecopy($newimage, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $imageWidth, $imageHeight);

    //get extension of the cropped image
    $ext = end(explode('.' , $imageName));

    //timestamp it
    $timestamp = time();

    //rename the new image
    $fileName = rand() . $timestamp . '.' . $ext;

    //unlink old image
    unlink($src);

    //update the DB with new imagename
    $update = array('update' => $this->image->update($imageID, $fileName));

    //Set the path for the image
    $path = 'data/gallery/' . $galleryID . '/images/album/' . $fileName;

    //create the cropped image
    imagejpeg($newimage,$path,$jpeg_quality);
```

This works as expected, the canvas is extended to the right 840 pixels. What I would like to be able to do is extend the canvas to the left 840 pixels. Not sure how to make this happen.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually pretty simple once I deciphered all the parameters.

```
imagecopy ( resource dest_image, resource source_image, int dest_x, int dest_y, int source_x, int source_y, int source_width, int source_height)
```

- The destination image you're copying to
- The source image you're copying from
- The X co-ordinate you want to copy to
- The Y co-ordinate you want to copy to
- The X co-ordinate you want to copy from
- The y co-ordinate you want to copy from
- The width in pixels of the source image you want to copy
- The height in pixels of the source image you want to copy